# Get an item's recordtype in a search result?

Tags: netsuite

I'm needing to include an item's recordtype in a search result.  Currently I'm using `{item.type.id}` which gives me the Name of the type, such as Service.  I'm trying to 'serviceitem' as the record type in the example I've just given.

The script I'm dealing with loops over some search results and needs to load or submit a field on items returned.  Both `nlapiSubmitField()` and `nlapiLoadRecord()` require the specific recordtype, as 'item' doesn't work.  Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Cheers,
PJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no `record type` field which you can query.

However, an alternative is to write a `formula text` field in the search column which can achieve this but, requires you to know record label and types before hand. Below is a formula to achieve the same.

```
CASE {type} 
WHEN 'Service' THEN 'serviceitem'  
WHEN 'Inventory Item' THEN 'inventoryitem'  
WHEN 'Non-inventory Item' THEN 'noninventoryitem' 
WHEN 'Kit/Package' THEN 'kititem'  
WHEN 'Other Charge' THEN 'otherchargeitem' 
WHEN 'Payment' THEN 'paymentitem'  
WHEN 'Subtotal' THEN 'subtotalitem' 
WHEN 'Assembly/Bill of Materials' THEN 'assemblyitem'  
WHEN 'Discount' THEN 'discountitem'  
WHEN 'Description' THEN 'descriptionitem'  
WHEN 'Markup' THEN 'markupitem'  
ELSE {type} END
```

If you are interested in getting the record type for item types, the other option is create/load an item type in UI and in the browser console use `nlapiGetRecordType()`

Comment: Thanks for the info, although I really hope you're wrong :).  I want to avoid having to map item.type.id's to record types, but I'm starting to think that may be my only choice, in which case I'll be using nlapiGetRecordType a whole lot to make a list.  The problem is the script needs to do a SubmitField (or alternatively load the record and update the field manually) on an item, both seem to require knowing the record type :(.

Comment: I just re-read your answer and noticed the code example is exactly that table :).  Cheers!  Much appreciated!